# How to cancel previews incomplete HTTP requests of the same type in a service in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using Angular 9 in my web app. I'm using a lot of services to connect to a web service. Sometimes a lot of identical requests are sent to a service. Maybe when a user click on a button repeatedly.

I want to cancel previews incomplete requests for all of my services. What's the best solution? (Maybe using RXJS)

This is one of my service functions:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getList(options?: ApiListOptions) {
  return this.http.post<ApiResponse<UserGet[]>>(
    environment.apiRoot + 'user/list',
    options,
    { headers: this.headers() }
  );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The RxJS `switchMap` operator is what you're looking for. The official Angular documentation for `HttpClient` has a section covering the latter and how it pertains to request cancellation. https://angular.io/guide/http#switchmap

Comment: you're looking for switchMap rxjs operator. it cancels the pending requests. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap

Answer (score 0):

Please try below with takeUntil rxjs operator you will be able to do the same.

```
export class YourComponent {
   protected ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

   [...]

   public httpGet(): void {
      this.http.get()
         .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
         .subscribe( (data) => { ... })
   }

   public ngOnDestroy(): void {
       this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
       this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd use a boolean variable instead of a Subject.

Comment: Yes you can using subject gives you the flexibility.

Comment: True, but in your example is just an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, like frequent button clicks, you can use `switchMap()` combine with `debounceTime()` to limit the frequency of action and http calls. You can use `Subject` for action trigger instead of component method

```
<button click="getList.next()">click</button>

getList=new Subject()
getList.pipe(debounceTime(2000),switchMap(()=>
this.http.post<ApiResponse<UserGet[]>>(
    environment.apiRoot + 'user/list',
    options,
    { headers: this.headers() }
  );
)).subscribe()
```